# QGIS: Add Polygon feature - I want to click on each vertex, but I'm stuck on the curser travel defining the polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

In QGIS, I have been happily creating polygons using "Add Polygon feature" and clicking each vertex to create my polygon, right click to complete.
Now for some reason, The Vertex tool has appeared next to Add Polygon feature and I can't click each vertex anymore. Wherever I move the cursor, this new line forms part of the polygon. It's no good for this work, I want to return to my vertex clicking mode, but I can't see how to get there.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot showing the issue you mention?  You say "*the Vertex tool has appeared next to Add Polygon feature*". "The Vertex tool" is next to "Add Polygon Feature" by default. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Kadir. I may not have noticed the Vertex Tool before. Add Polygon Feature is now stuck on drawing circles, which is also un useful.

Comment: How would I attach a screen shot?

Comment: Please read this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135485/398935